# releasing dynamic memory of pointer of pointers in C

Tags: c, dynamic, free

I have an error while trying to release memory of dynamic array.

```
void Ex()
{
 int **Matrix = dyn_matrix_allocation(rows, cols);
.
.
.
    free_My_Dyn_Mem(Matrix, rows);
}

void free_My_Dyn_Mem(int **to_Release, int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        free(to_Release[i]);
//free(to_Release); - If I do this, the program crash.
}

void **dyn_matrix_allocation(int rows, int cols)
{
    void **matrix = (void**)calloc (sizeof(int*), cols);
    assert(matrix); /*calloc worked*/
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = (int*)calloc(sizeof(int), rows);
        assert(matrix[i]); /*calloc worked*/
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

after releasing the array itself, I'm trying to release the pointer of pointers `(**matrix)` then I get an error. debugger shows nothing special. any ideas why?

Comment: Wrong allocation. Check the for loop it should iterate for the columns just allocates not the rows you are allocating in the loop.

Comment: @Frankie this works the opposite.. check yourself

Comment: are you sure you are not messing up Matrix before passing it to free.

Comment: @ofek no need to check. Just a suggestion never be so sure of your work.

Comment: @Frankie ofcourse, but try to think about the order when you first allocate memory for the rows. Anyway i was trying to change but unfortunely it didn't work

Comment: The fact that you mix cast of malloc, `int *` and `void *` for no reason don't make any sense.

Comment: @OfekPintok I could not add any more detail because of limits of my mobile device. See my answer below.

Comment: @Stargateur Oh yes, just fast and dirty. I changed it. Of course I removed casting of `calloc` that are not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a couple of errors in allocating your dynamic matrix due to unclear definition of your 2D addressing.

First error in allocation, here you choose to create your matrix column dependent allocating an array of `cols` pointers ti `int`:

```
void **matrix = (void**)calloc (sizeof(int*), cols);
```

Now you **should allocate an array of `rows` integers per each column**, but you assign `rows` arrays of integers:

```
for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)  //Should be for (i = 0; i < cols; i++)
{
    matrix[i] = (int*)calloc(sizeof(int), rows);
    assert(matrix[i]); /*calloc worked*/
}
```

Up to now some compilers, or lint or even good debuggers should have told you that you where outside bounds.

But the exception triggers when you free the memory still using the wrong addressing.

```
void Ex()
{
 int **Matrix = dyn_matrix_allocation(rows, cols);
.
.
.
    free_My_Dyn_Mem(Matrix, rows);  //But you allocated cols pointers...
}
```

You should pass the array of integer pointers that has a size of `cols` members, not `rows`.

Now you release what you allocated out of bounds:

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    free(to_Release[i]);
```

The debugger should have complained a lot!

Then you release a now corrupted memory...

```
free(to_Release);
```

Your code should be:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

void free_My_Dyn_Mem(int **to_Release, int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        free(to_Release[i]);
    free(to_Release);   //- If I do this, the program crash.
}

int **dyn_matrix_allocation(int rows, int cols)
{
    int **matrix = calloc(sizeof(int *), cols);
    assert(matrix); /*calloc worked */
    int i;
    //for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    for (i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = calloc(sizeof(int), rows);
        assert(matrix[i]);  /*calloc worked */
    }
    return matrix;
}

void Ex(void)
{
    int rows = 100;
    int cols = 20;
    int **Matrix = dyn_matrix_allocation(rows, cols);
//.
//.
//.
    //free_My_Dyn_Mem(Matrix, rows);
    free_My_Dyn_Mem(Matrix, cols);
}
```

Remember that you chosen a columns ordered matrix.

P.S. I forget to add that asserts are normally used for development checks and they can be removed defining the symbol `NDEBUG`. When you need a permanent control, like an error on allocation return, you should use standard `if (condition) ErrorHandling(...);`.

Comment: The code "should" be at least like [this](http://rextester.com/CUPZ30119)

Comment: @Stargateur Yes nice code. Only in function `free_mat` if the matrix pointer `mat` is NULL you free it anyway.